# How to split a UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: uitextfield, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I have a UIToolbar with two UIBarButtonItems ("previous" and "next"), which I use as an inputAccessoryView for my UITextFields. These buttons cycle through the text fields.

I have seen in some places that the buttons are actually a single split button. How would I achieve this?

Here's an image:

[image: Previous-Next Split Button]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the UISegmented Control button. If that's not it, then post an image of what button you want so we can better help you.

Comment: Yep... that a Segmented Control button. See:  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW27